# Escaping Commas in m4 ifdef Statements

Tags: markdown, m4

I'm using a combination of markdown and m4 to produce three different versions of a document depending on the flags given at the beginning. Let's call them Gold, Silver, and Bronze.

The problem that I've come across is that if I have a section that appears within an ifdef statement that has commas, m4 considers the rest of the section to be false.

```
ifdef(`GOLDANDSILVER',dnl
## Here's a subsection header

### Subsubsection about this, that, and the other thing

Aren't examples fun? Here's some punctuation, failure, and misfortune.
)dnl
```

Interestingly, it does not fail on the subsubsection, but fails in the body text.

My current, ugly, solution is to use a 'dummy comma' that can be piped to, and replaced by, sed.

```
ifdef(`GOLDANDSILVER',dnl
## Here's a subsection header

### Subsubsection about thisREPLACE_ME_COMMA thatREPLACE_ME_COMMA and the other thing

Aren't examples fun? Here's some punctuationREPLACE_ME_COMMA failureREPLACE_ME_COMMA and misfortune.
)dnl
```

I'm looking for a cleaner, preferably m4-only, solution that allows me to have "," in the body of my ifdef statements.

---

What I've learned by trial and error:

- m4 seems to ignore any content or definitions on lines prefixed with #
- [,] does not escape a comma
- [[,]] does not escape a comma

Comment: Did you see my answer? Does it work?

Comment: It works on a small scale, but for whatever reason, there's something else in the document that causes it to no longer compile to HTML.

For now, I'll just stick with REPLACE_ME_COMMA.

Comment: If you provide a complex example I can check it.

Comment: https://comp.mail.sendmail.narkive.com/2JrKqHp4/how-to-escape-commas-in-m4#post2

Example:
define(`INBOUND_CIDRS_VAL', ``"0.0.0.0/0, ::/0"'')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best idea is to use string delimiters. The default string delimiters aren't the best solution (I think) - but you can change them with `changequote`.

You can change the comment delimiters (default is `#` and newline) - even can disable them.

I think the following will be good for you:

```
ifdef(`GOLDANDSILVER',changequote(XXX,YYY)dnl
XXX## Here's a subsection header

### Subsubsection about this, that, and the other thing

Aren't examples fun? Here's some punctuation, failure, and misfortune.YYY changequote()
)dnl
```

Please note the `changequote(XXX,YYY)`: the quote begins with `XXX` and ends with `YYY`. In this case the line begin with `#` isn't comment because it's part of a string. And please note the `changequote()`: it restores the default string delimiters.

```
$  cat x.m4 | m4 -DGOLDANDSILVER # GOLDANDSILVER is defined
## Here's a subsection header

### Subsubsection about this, that, and the other thing

Aren't examples fun? Here's some punctuation, failure, and misfortune.
$  cat x.m4 | m4 # GOLDANDSILVER isn't defined
$
```